# Convert an unit -> unit to Action

Tags: linq, f#, linq-expressions, hangfire

To use Hangfire in combination with F# I require a little help:

Hangfire's `BackgroundJob.Enqueue` takes as a parameter an [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) with generic type `Action<'T>`.

So in full: [`Expression<Action<'T>>`](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-in-background.html)

And on my side I've got a method to my disposal:

`let doSomething () = ()`
Thus its signature is `unit -> unit`.

How I could perfectly pass in `Action(doSomething)` if the callee took an `Action`, but it does not.

So how do I convert my `unit -> unit` to a `Expression<Action<'T>>`?

Comment: Converting `someFunc` of type `unit -> unit` into `Action<unit>` is as simple as `Action(someFunc)`. However, converting a function into a LINQ expression is a bit more difficult. See [this answer to a different question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23146624/24380) for an example that might be of help.

Comment: There's a type-directed conversion from syntactic F# functions to `Expression<_>`s when used as method arguments, so try just calling `Enqueue(fun () -> doSomething())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As kvb said in a comment, F# supports converting lambdas to `Expression`s, just like C#. So, if you want to create an expression that ignores its input and invokes `doSomething`, it's just:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(fun x -> doSomething())
```

Comment: Seems like I missed something regarding the input parameters. Thanks!