# Set UseHeaderRow on ExcelDataReader AsDataSet ExcelDataSetConfiguration from F#

Tags: lambda, f#, c#-to-f#, exceldatareader

Using the ExcelDataReader within a F# project.
To use the first row as Column names (headers) the configuration needs to be adjusted with the following C# code:

```
var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration() {
    ConfigureDataTable = (_) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration() {
        UseHeaderRow = true
    }
});
```

As is explained in https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#important-note-when-upgrading-from-exceldatareader-2x

If I try to translate this to F# code:

```
let result = reader.AsDataSet (
  new ExcelDataSetConfiguration ( 
     ConfigureDataTable = ExcelDataTableConfiguration ( 
        UseHeaderRow = true)
     )
  )
```

I get the following error:

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have
type 'Func<IExcelDataReader,ExcelDataTableConfiguration>' but here has
type 'ExcelDataTableConfiguration'
```

If I understand well, I will have to pass a Linq expression, so I looked at some examples:

http://www.fssnip.net/ts/title/F-lambda-to-C-LINQ-Expression

[How do I create a Linq expression tree with an F# lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146473/how-do-i-create-a-linq-expression-tree-with-an-f-lambda)

Unfortunately I didn't manage to solve this problem.
Any pointers will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Property `ConfigureDataTable` is of type `Func<_,_>`, but you're trying to assign an `ExcelDataTableConfiguration` to it.

Comment: You're right, I was messing a bit with the F# lambda functions, but you pointed me to the answer:

`let result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration(  ConfigureDataTable = fun (_:IExcelDataReader) -> ExcelDataTableConfiguration( UseHeaderRow = true)))`
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, more simple than I thought:

```
let result = reader.AsDataSet(
  new ExcelDataSetConfiguration( 
    ConfigureDataTable = 
      fun (_:IExcelDataReader) -> ExcelDataTableConfiguration( UseHeaderRow = true)
    )
  )
```

@Fyodor Soikin, thank you for the support!

Hope this helps others with the same issue.